# Assign a different value to a drop down selection

Tags: python, tkinter, drop-down-menu, pycharm

I have a drop-down with 7 choices for my calculating program. I would like to assign a different value to each choice so that when a user makes a selection, the alternate value is passed to the formula for making the calculation. For example, if the user selects 42, the alternate value would be 2143, which would be passed to the ohms = float(e4.get()) portion of my formula. How would I do this? I am using PyCharm.

```
from tkinter import *
import os
os.system('clear')

root = Tk()
root.title('Pickup Coil Turn Count Calculator')
root.geometry("400x700")
root.configure(bg='#ffc773')


#turn_count holds the math formula for the calculation
def turn_count():
    width, length, ohms, resistance = float(e2.get()), float(e3.get()), float(e4.get()), float(e5.get())
    turn_count = resistance / ohms * 1000 * 12 / ((width * 3.14) + length + length - width * .19) * .969
    count_label['text'] = int(turn_count)

#for the reset button
def clear_fields():
    e1.delete(0, 'end')
    e2.delete(0, 'end')
    e3.delete(0, 'end')
    clicked.set(options[0])
    e5.delete(0, 'end')
    count_label.config(text='')


myLabel = Label(root, text='Enter Core Height', bg='#ffc773')
myLabel.pack(pady=10)
e1 = Entry(root, width=10, justify='center', border=0)
e1.pack()

myLabel = Label(root, text='Enter Core Width', bg='#ffc773')
myLabel.pack(pady=10)
e2 = Entry(root, width=10, justify='center', border=0)
e2.pack()

myLabel = Label(root, text='Enter Core Length', bg='#ffc773')
myLabel.pack(pady=10)
e3 = Entry(root, width=10, justify='center', border=0)
e3.pack()

myLabel = Label(root, text='Select Wire Gauge', bg='#ffc773')
myLabel.pack(pady=10)

#each option would have an alternate value
options = [
    '38',
    '39',
    '40',
    '41',
    '42',
    '43',
    '44',
]

clicked = IntVar()
clicked.set(options[0])

drop = OptionMenu(root, clicked, *options)
drop.pack()

myLabel = Label(root, text='Enter Target Resistance In Ohms', bg='#ffc773')
myLabel.pack(pady=10)
e5 = Entry(root, width=10, justify='center', border=0)
e5.pack()

Button(root, text='Calculate', command=turn_count).pack(pady=40)

myLabel = Label(root, text='Turn Count', bg='#ffc773')
myLabel.pack()

count_label = Label(root, width=10)
count_label.pack()

Button(root, text='Reset', command=clear_fields).pack(pady=30)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding to [@Cambuchi's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66645986/14094985), you can do the following to implement it

```py
options = {
    '42':2143.0,
    '38':1234.0,
    '39':5678.0
}

clicked = StringVar()
clicked.set(list(options.keys())[0])

drop = OptionMenu(root, clicked, *options.keys())
drop.pack()
```

Note that I have used `StringVar` instead of `IntVar` since the dictionary keys are stings and we need it to return a string when `get` method is used on it. You can directly have the values as `float` and avoid casting it later.

```py
ohms = options[clicked.get()]
```

Comment: I got the "Expected type 'float', got 'str' instead" error. How do I convert the str to a float?

Comment: @HighlineGuitars Where did you get this error?

Comment: I got it in my definition for ohms. However, I solved it by changing the def to what you had originally suggested before editing your answer. float(options[clicked.get()]) It works and for that, I thank you.

Comment: @HighlineGuitars Glad to be of help, additionally when I edited my answer, I also edit the dictionary to store float values, if you use the current dict, it wouldn't produce the error, if you use a dict with sting values, then you would need to cast it.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a good use case for dictionaries. Perhaps use a dictionary with the key:value pair corresponding to the value:alternate value pair? For key that is selected you would pass in the value. Combine this with the `command` option in `optionmenu` to get the desired effect.

```
option_keys = [38, 39, 42]
options = {'38':'1234',
           '39':'5678',
           '42':'2143'} # example provided
```

Then you would call something like:

```
from tkinter import *

def func(value):
    print(options[value])

root = Tk()
var = StringVar()
drop = OptionMenu(root, var, *option_keys, command=func)
drop.place(x=10, y=10)
```

Comment: I believe `options[0].value` is incorrect. Dictionaries are not indexed, this would mean that you are passing a key `0` to the dictionary, which doesn't exist in this case. Even if you did `options['38'].value` you would get an error as it would return the value `'1234'` and it does not have an attribute `value`.

Comment: Yes you are correct. It would just be options[<key>].